# Bootstrap 3 form checkbox label doesn't align with checkbox input in Chromium + Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

In both chrome and firefox:

- `form-inline` causes the label to be shifted downwards and the space between the checkbox and the label is narrower than when using `form-horizontal`.
- `form-horizontal` displays perfectly

#### [Here's a demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn9Up/)

#### Here's some code:

```html
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"/> Test againn
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Here's a screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to make the checkboxes all aligned correctly in both browsers or am I missing something?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is actually an issue in all browsers <sup>(that I've tested)</sup>

**Here's a screenshot** - *I added a grey border so it's easier to tell that it's not lining up*.

[image: screenshot]

### [Here's a demo that reproduces the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/m3RHG/1/)

The issue occurs when the [**inline form**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) is on a screen that is larger than `768px`.

Particularly, the thing that messes up the alignment is from this [line of forms.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/forms.less#L452) (which was introduced with [this commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/a82ca0f9e1711b32f7c07e23ea1e23dd253cd21e#diff-57a5fbf005ecc202d1e7e08c11f73b93)):

```css
float: none;
```

Naively, setting this value back to `float: left` seems to fix the problem, but I'm not sure what other issues may arise.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .form-inline .radio input[type="radio"], 
    .form-inline .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

#### [Here's a working version of your code with these changes](http://jsfiddle.net/gn9Up/2/)

Other than that, you'd just have to tweak the CSS

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug report / pull request with Bootstrap?

Comment: No, just curious if you did. Anyway, for the record for BS3 at least it's closed as *won't fix* - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15791, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13936

Answer (score 19):

I got mine works after changing `radio or checkbox` to `radio-inline or checkbox-inline` class

http://jsfiddle.net/gn9Up/57/

Comment: yes, but if you re-size your browser to xs size you will not get "vertical form" for your checkboxes, it will remain to be inlined.

Answer (score 7):

In my case none of the answers resolved the issue. This is what I did to align correctly the input with the label. A have added 2px to the margin top. In **bootstrap.css** it is set to 4px. Setting it to 6px  "fix" the issue.

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin: 6px 0 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value=""> Label text
</label>
```

Comment: This solution was the only one that worked for me! thank you!!